# Toggle text with Show/Hide Fade & Slide

Tags: jquery, text, toggle, show-hide, fade

This is my first post on stack overflow.

I've got a show/hide with a fade and slide which is open when the page is loaded. It is working great.

I just want to change the text from "x" when open and "-" when closed.

Here is the script I am using, which I got from another question on stackoverflow.

```
function toggleSlider() {
    if ($(".slidingDiv").is(":visible")) {
        $("#contentThatFades").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(600, function(){
            $("#contentThatFades").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }   
}
```

---

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>


    <!-- The 1140px Grid - http://cssgrid.net/ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1140.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleSlider() {
        if ($(".slidingDiv").is(":visible")) {
            $("#contentThatFades").fadeTo(600, 0, function(){
                    $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
                    $("#closebutton").text("-");
                }
            );
        } else {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(600, function(){
                $("#closebutton").text("x");
                $("#contentThatFades").fadeTo(600, 1);
            });
        }   
    }

    $('#closebutton').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleSlider();
        });</script>


</head>



<body>


<div class="container top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="threecol">
        <a href="#" id="closebutton">x</a>
        </div>
        <div class="twocol">
        Text
        </div>
        <div class="twocol">
        Text
        </div>
        <div class="threecol">
        </div>
        <div class="twocol last">
        Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container slidingDiv">
    <div id="contentThatFades" style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=1);">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="threecol">
            <h1>Text</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="fivecol">
            Text
            </div>
            <div class="fourcol last">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't mention that text content of which element should be changed. How do you call the function?

Comment: Don't know if this can help you. http://jsfiddle.net/Q3LEp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function toggleSlider() {
        if ($(".slidingDiv").is(":visible")) {
            $("#contentThatFades").fadeTo(600, 0, function(){
                    $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
                    $("#closebutton").text("-");
                }
            );
        } else {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(600, function(){
                $("#closebutton").text("x");
                $("#contentThatFades").fadeTo(600, 1);
            });
        }   
    }

    $('#closebutton').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleSlider();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your comment but it is not working.

I realised that I didn't end include my HTML.

It is set up like

 <div class="threecol">
        <a href="#" id="closebutton" onclick="toggleSlider();">–</a>
  </div>

<div id="contentThatFades" style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=1);">
Content
</div>

Comment: I've altered my code so it uses `fadeTo()` rather than `animate()`, and better reflects your HTML (make sure you take the `onclick` off of your link tag). Did you add the `filter` style in yourself? There could also be something else in your code that's blocking things. Which browser are you using, and are you seeing any errors in its developer tools?

Comment: I've taken out the onclick and still not working. I'm not too sure what you mean filter to the style.

I'm not seeing any errors in developer tools, using safari and chrome on mac. Linking to jquery library and a mediaqueries script

Ive edited my post so you can see my html 

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the inline style tag from `contentThatFades`: `<div id="contentThatFades">`. The `filter:alpha(opacity=1);` may be screwing things up.

Comment: hello, sorry that is not working. the script i originally posted was working fine just didn't have the text change. Also i didnt add the filter style in myself.

i am using <script type="text/javascript"> </script> is that right?

Comment: Using the bare bones HTML that you've provided, and the jQuery from my answer, you can see a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/439cg/ The container fades in and out, and the text of the link changes as requested. What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: Hello, I edited my question so I put my whole HTML code in.

The jsfiddle link you sent me is working great. But when I copy and paste the it doesn't work on my file at all. I got a token error so deleted all the spaces but another error shows that "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on". 

At the moment it doesn't fade, slide or the text doesn't change it just stays the same as how it is loaded.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? on() only got introduced in 1.7. You can use  $('#closebutton').click(function(e){ instead, if you're running an older version.

Comment: I am using the latest now, but had v 1.6. I moved the script to the bottom of the page and its working perfectly now! Can not thank you enough